# Clearing text input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an input field:

> `<input name="test1" class="t-input" id="test1" style="color: #fff;" type="text" value="3.05"/`

I am trying to change the value or clear the value through jquery, I've tried all of these and none of them are working. The value changes, but I have to click on the textbox to see the change take effect. Am I missing something?

```
$('#test1').val('');
$('#test1').val("");
$('#test1').val("").change(); 
$('#test1').val("").trigger('change');
$('#test1').attr(value,'');
```

Comment: when did you want to clear it? after a submit? after a button is clicked?

Comment: when do you want the value to be changed ? When the page loads, when the user clicks, when button is submitted etc. Basically, after which event do you want the values to change ?

Comment: Most of your examples should work, so we're missing a piece of the puzzle here

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/mnVs7/3/ Check what are you missing

Comment: i am clearing several other labels, triggered by event dropdown onChange event, i don't know either what am i missing...

Comment: value changes as soon as i click on the textbox...i don't think it has something to do with DOM not being built...any other ideas???

Comment: Can you share your code.. It will be easier to see what exactly is happening??

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you try to work with it when dom is not built yet, try to use `ready` event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // your code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wait your page to be fully loaded ( *ready* in jquery ) to update your field :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#test1').val('');
    });

</script>
```

if that's not working, you probably need to read your Error Console (ctrl + shift + j on Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#test1").removeAttr("value")
```

This will do your job i guess.

Comment: Or maybe `$("#test1").remove()`?

Comment: Definitely not .remove(), that'll get rid of the entire element.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Yes, removing the attribute or the element is _not_ a solution. I meant that, OP is trying to clear the value not removing the attribute.

Comment: @undefined sorry its my mistake.]

Comment: @MikeRobinson thanks for the support but undefined is trying to tell me sarcastically, that opponent wants to clear the value, :)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh No, please don't say sorry, only it's not a good option for current problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the document.ready function. try encasing your code in it..
Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/YUYkT/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok Got it!!

It is a text box being rendered using telerik mvc controls. So this is how you clear it.

$('#text1').data("tTextBox").value('');